# Public DNS domain entry overriding with active directory dns 2008 R2 server

Tags: active-directory, dns-zone

we own a DNS domain who looks like ma.com

We would like to create development environment using the same domain, but pointing to our private IP addresses. For example, i would like dev.ma.com to be resolved to 192.168.1.1.

So basically, i would like my 2008 R2 active directory server to answer for dev.ma.com (and returning my ip address) but not for all other entries of ma.com, managed by our public dns server (not related to active directory).

I saw there are conditional forwarders but i can't figure out how to use these feature to achieve this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your activedirectory DNS will be zone authority, so it will not look anywhere else for records matching the domain.
Instead, create the records in both internal and external DNS for the ones going to external IPs.

Comment: You need to configure your environment for split-brain DNS: [http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/set-up-split-brain-dns-with-active-directory-integrated-zones/](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/set-up-split-brain-dns-with-active-directory-integrated-zones/)

Comment: Split brain DNS will make the Internal DNS Server authoritative for the zone and every record in it. the question states that the internal DNS should only be responsible for a single entry not them all. so Split-Brain DNS wont work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to use Pinpoint DNS. With pinpoint DNS you can configure your internal DNS servers to resolve a single name like Dev.ma.dns to an internal IP Address while making sure that your internal DNS Server is not considered authoritative for the rest of the zone. Those records will continue to be resolved by your Public DNS Servers. Check out the link below for a more detailed description of Pinpoint DNS:

http://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/SLN164005/configuring-a-pinpoint-dns-zone-in-windows-server?lang=EN

Hope this helps.

Mike.